# I am trying to insert data into mysql database. But my code is not working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am working on a form and learning MySQL. I want to insert just data into a MySQL Database.
Here are my files.

My insert.php file contains this:

```
 <?php
include_once('ressources/init.php');
if ( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['contents'])){
    // Here we use MySQL-Code
    mysql_query("
        INSERT INTO `posts` SET
            `title` = '{$_POST['title']}',
            `contents` = '{$_POST['contents']}'
    ");
}
 ?>

 <html lang="en">
 <head>
<title>Simple Form</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<form action="">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text">
            <label for="post">Post:</label>
            <textarea name="post" id="post" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my init.php contains:

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
mysql_select_db(DB_NAME);
?>
```

And my last file is the config.php:

```
 <?php
$config['db_host'] = 'localhost';
$config['db_user'] = 'root';
$config['db_pass'] = 'root';
$config['db_name'] = 'php_tutorial';

foreach ( $config as $k => $v ){
    define(strtoupper($k), $v);
}
 ?>
```

The login data should be correct. And I don't know, why it isn't possible for me, to fill the database with new data. Any help and any tip would be appreciated.

Here is a link to a picture of my phpmyadmin control panel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9dBv.jpg

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: You should really watch out for [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)....

Comment: You didn't mention what problem you're facing. What is the question?

Comment: There are many, many things wrong here. Start by finding a tutorial on `mysqli`, not `mysql`. The `'mysql_*` functions are deprecated and will be removed soon.

Comment: @MikeW: these functions are deprecated and already removed.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @shmuli `mysql` is deprecated in PHP 5.5, but still supported. It _might_ be removed in PHP 5.6, but that's not out yet.

Comment: @bjanka Please see my updated answer with the full code for insert.php using mysql.

Comment: @bjanka: I believe I have made all necessary modifications to get your code to function as you would like (using mysql).  It would be helpful to know if we have solved your issue with code suggested in my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

change `<form action="">` to `<form method="POST">` - this will do the trick

next item `<input type="text">` change it to `<input type="text" name="title">`

also, consider SQL injection problem in your code, use `mysql_escape_string`, also instead of `$_POST` you can use `$_REQUEST` array

and dont forget to use `mysql_query(...) or die(mysql_error());`

UPDATE: thanks to @Neal - of course do not use deprecated and obsolete MYSQL_ api, use MYSQLI or PDO instead, with parametric queries

Comment: @Neal what is the problem?

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and will be [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in the future. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/msqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: Ok... but this was only for learning about it. Not actually a real project. But still you're saying to switch to MySQLi?

Comment: @bjankamuhametaj for test project of course you can do anything, but you should know that it is old and inefficient way, mysqli better, faster and provide more functions, for real projects use only mysqli or pdo (as it is wrapper on mysqli)

Comment: @bjanka, If learning, you might as well not be learning obsolete syntax/functions which will eventually break.  As the others have said, use mysqli/pdo, until then, please consider my answer for a non mysqli approach.

Comment: Don't use `or die(mysql_error());` for production environments, only for testing.  Of course, that goes for the entire mysql functionality, again, in the future, go with mysqli/pdo.

Answer (score 0):

First, you will want to stop using mysql and switch to mysqli/PDO.

That said, using your current code,

YOUR insert.php SHOULD BE:

```
<?php
include_once('ressources/init.php');
if (isset($_POST['title']){
    $title = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['title']);
    $contents = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contents']);
    $q="INSERT INTO posts SET (title, contents) VALUES ('$title','$contents')"; 
    mysql_query($q);
}
?>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Simple Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input name="title" type="text">
            <label for="contents">Post:</label>
            <textarea name="contents" id="contents" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The mysql_real_escape_string() function will help prevent injections (harmful characters will be escaped from your query string).

That should get you started.

Also, as a security side note: If you have not already, make sure and put your config.php file below your site's public root folder to help protect your mysql username/password from being easily viewed in browsers/etc..

Answer (score -1):

You can try with PDO:
(copy from php.net and modified)

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.DB_NAME.';host='.DB_HOST;

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

in your form there is a code like:

```
  <input type="text">
```

Please specify the name of the field like:

```
  <input type="text" name="title">
```

later, you can get the content of this field like $_GET['title'].
Because of the limitations of GET requests, will be good if you add method="POST" to your form.

```
<form action="" method="POST">
```

you can get title like $_POST['title']

```
if ( isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['contents'])){
    // Here we use MySQL-Code
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("
        INSERT INTO posts  (title, contents) VALUES(:title, :post)
    ");
  $stmt->bind_value(':title', $_POST['title']);
  $stmt->bind_value(':post', $_POST['post');
  $stmt->execute();
}
```

I'm not 100% sure that mysql support named parameters, but you can try.